# No desktop icons on Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, plasma, desktop-icons

I just installed Plasma desktop on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine.The installation went fine but I think something was not installed properly.No desktop icons are appearing.Also, I read somewhere that I have to enable folder view from desktop settings->layout but there is no layout option in desktop settings.Please help me out.
P.S:when I log out or shut down, a brief flash of desktop with all icons appears.

Comment: Related http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297820&goto=newpost/

Answer (score 3):

There is desktop settings and system settings, you seem to be in system settings.

To get to desktop settings, right click the desktop and then desktop settings then choose Layout.

I don't think any thing is wrong with the install, folder view is a widget and off by default.